# How to set RESTful methods in API URL for web services in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I am working on one project where following things are expected,

1. To write a web service to get users list and individual users information
2. To write a web service to do CRUD operations.

I understand that GET method will be useful for fetching information and execution of that API call via browser but can any one help me for following items?,

- To make API call if I want to use "PUT", or "POST" or "DELETE" methods? How to do it via browser? or what would be best way to do it?
- I have to use Stored procedure to fetch the information from DB for GET method?

Comment: You can use AJAX, or with HTML only, you can use method override with a hidden _method input or a _method query parameter. The stored procedure depends on your server side implementation. It is not necessary if you don't want to. REST is very similar to normal webpages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a **slim Php microframework**, it provides a powerful, extensible framework for building a REST API.
So, The typical REST conventions for URL requests you'll use:

```
GET /items: Retrieve a list of items
GET /items/22: Retrieve item 22
POST /items: Create a new item
PUT /items/22: Update item 22
DELETE /items/22: Remove item 22
```

Slim's URL router will help you to make it easier.
And YES, you have to create your data object to fetch from server's side, one tipycall example to get it:

```
// handle GET requests for /articles/:id
$app->get('/items/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {    
  try {
    // query database for single items
    $items = R::findOne('items', 'id=?', array($id));

    if ($items) {
      // if found, return JSON response
      $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      echo json_encode(R::exportAll($items));
    } else {
      // else throw exception
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
  } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
    // return 404 server error
    $app->response()->status(404);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $app->response()->status(400);
    $app->response()->header('X-Status-Reason', $e->getMessage());
  }
});
```

Finally, this tutorial may help you to a total work around 
[http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/][1]